# Copying distinct rows from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, I can copy one table into another by doing:

```
Select * into desttable from sourcetable
```

However, there are duplicate rows in sourcetable and I would like to just copy distinct rows. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: The clue is in the question :)

Comment: Very zen, @Phil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are true EXACT duplicates, you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
INTO NewTable
FROM Sourcetable
```

If they aren't exact dupes in every single field, then we need more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct *
into YourDestTable
from YourSourceTable
```

This will select only distinct rows into `YourDestTable` upon creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this activity using ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITION BY clause. This partition clause identified set of duplicate records and row_number assign an ID for this set.